# Bootstrap 3 2-column form layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am still learning the proper use of Bootstrap 3 and was wondering if you all could help me out. I would like a layout something like this:

```
Label                        Label
Textbox                      Textbox

Label                        Label
Textbox                      Textbox

Label                        Label
Textbox Textbox              Textarea
```

I know that if I use the .form-group it will allow me to accomplish the Label over the top of the textbox. How can I assure that this happens in a column yet allows for some inline things like the example with the two textboxes alongside each other?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, you can use the grid system to layout your inputs and labels anyway that you want.  The trick is to remember that you can use rows within your columns to break them into twelfths as well.

The example below is one possible way to accomplish your goal and will put the two text boxes near Label3 on the same line when the screen is small or larger.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
            <label>Label1</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
            <label>Label2</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-12">Label3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
            <label>Label4</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m3u8bjv0/2/

Comment: There's no form tag in your code but it's important to remember that when using the grid system to style forms like this not to include any form classes on your forms such as 'form-horizontal' otherwise it will break your layout.

Answer (score 16):

You could use the bootstrap grid system :

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label for="textbox1">Label1</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="textbox1" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
    <label for="textbox2">Label2</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="textbox2" type="text"/>
</div>
<span class="clearfix">
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: No, I stuck this into jsfiddle and got a stack of labels and form fields. See it here http://jsfiddle.net/mikemahony/3jHqH/

Comment: extend the result window in jsfiddle, it will go inline, it's responsive. if you do not want responsivity use a simple <table></table> layout.

Comment: I extended the result window in JSFiddle and your code isn't responsive. I can also see from the HTML that it doesn't conform with the example I give above. The example above shows a label and then UNDER the label a textbox. You have label, label, textbox, textbox. Hit up the JSFiddle in my last comment and you will see that your code just stacks 2 labels and 2 textboxes. Thanks though

Comment: You edited your post in the meantime. I updated thejsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3jHqH/4/) to match your edit. It is not my code being responsive, it is bootstrap, have a look to the grid system and col classes. :)

Comment: I understand where the responsiveness is coming from. However, the key element to my question is the two textboxes next to each other with just one label above. What seems to happen is that I wind up with everything the way you laid it out.

Comment: You will also note that I was looking for a 2-column layout, side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bootstrap grid system. as Yoann said

---

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form role="form">
           <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-10 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    </div>
          </form>
         <div class="clearfix">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```