# Bootstrap unable to Divide form inline, what should i use to divide them into columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am new to bootstrap and learning it.I am trying to create an form page like this which i had made in JSP .This is a part of the page.
[image: Form Created in JSP]

But when trying with bootstrap , all i could come up was something like this. I would like to know which form / guideness on how to proceed to recreate the content .I tried using plain html . But i couldnt come up with a form like the one i made in JSP
[image]

Comment: add some code or wireframe or some thing! with this how can you expect a help?

Comment: @Praveen, have you seen https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ ? Using bootstrap grid with class `.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4` can be helpful to you

Comment: Will i be able to decrease the height of those columns.can i have  textbox and dropdown inside those ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
      <label>Label 1</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
      <label>Label 2</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Based on:

[Bootstrap 3 2-column form layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032759/bootstrap-3-2-column-form-layout)

Comment: I'm able to create those forms. I am trying to create something  3 rows and 4 columns . in 4 columns , i'm trying to keep two text box ans two dropdowns

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve and what problem you have.

Comment: I have posted the first image right, i'm trying to create one like that .But i'm failing